# $E[X_{n+1}\mid X_1,\ldots,X_{n}] =X_{n} \implies E[X_{n+1}] = E[X_n] = \ldots = E[X_2] = E[X_1]$

Tags: probability, expected-value, martingales

I saw from https://math.dartmouth.edu/~pw/math100w13/lalonde.pdf that

$$E[X_{n+1}\mid X_1,\ldots,X_{n}] =X_{n}   \implies E[X_{n+1}] = E[X_n] =\ldots = E[X_2] =  E[X_1]$$

Does this implication hold in general or only for a Martingale process? How do we show $E[X_{n+1}] = E[X_n] =\ldots = E[X_2] =  E[X_1]$

After some thinking, if I'm not mistaken, then the above relation follows from the law of total expectation. And it appears in general, not just to Martingale processes.

Here's my attempt at a proof:

We know

$$
E[X] = E[E[X|Y]]
$$

We can take the expected value of the Martingale property as follows:
$$
E[E[X_{n+1}\mid X_1,\ldots,X_{n}]] = E[X_{n}]
$$
From the law of total expectation, we know that the LHS gives $E[X_{n+1}]$
$$
\therefore E_{n+1} = E[X_n]
$$

And similarly, you can do the same process to show $E[X_n] = E[X_{n-1}]$ and so on.

Is this correct? Or am I arriving at the correct answer by doing something wrong?

Comment: What do you mean by $\cdots$?

Comment: @MacRance I edited the OP. Does that make it clearer?

Comment: What you have done is correct. It is  the only sensible way to prove this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a sequence $(X_n)_{n\ge 1}$ of random variables has the property that for every $n\ge 1$, $E[X_{n+1}\mid X_1,\dots,X_n] = X_n$, then implicit in this assumption is that each $X_n$ is integrable. Then this is the definition of what it means for $(X_n)_{n\ge 1}$ to be a martingale.

To prove that for martingales, the expectation of $X_n$ is independent of $n$, we apply the definition$^\dagger$ of conditional expectation:
$$
E[X_{n+1}] = E[E[X_{n+1}\mid X_1,\dots,X_n]] = E[X_n].
$$
Now, by induction if you like, or as $n\ge 1$ was arbitrary, the claim is proved.

---

$^\dagger$Recall that for an integrable random variable $X$, a $\sigma$-algebra $\mathscr F$, and any event $A\in\mathscr F$, the conditional expectation $E[X\mid\mathscr F]$ is an $\mathscr F$-measurable random variable that satisfies $E[X;A] = E[E[X \mid \mathscr F];A]$.  Applying this with $A = \Omega$ we recover the usual law of total expectation: $E[X] = E[E[X\mid \mathscr F]]$. Note that if $A$ is an event, $E[X;A]$ is not the same as $E[X\mid A]$: the first is a number with the interpretation of being a weighted average of $X$ amongst inputs from $A$, and the second is shorthand for the random variable $E[X\mid\sigma(A)]$, with the interpretation as the best guess of $X$ given the knowledge of whether $A$ has happened.

Comment: I'm new to the terminology $\sigma$-algebra. Is it correct to say that $\sigma$-algebra is a partition/subset of $\Omega$ and that the union of $\sigma$-algebra forms $\Omega$?

Comment: @user5965026: Not exactly. You should think of a $\sigma$-algebra as a collection of "events." So a $\sigma$-algebra as a mathematical object is a subset of the power set of $\Omega$ that satisfies some extra conditions. One way to think about the $\sigma$-algebra of a random variable $X$ is as the collection of all the "information" we have about $X$---denote it $\sigma(X)$. So inside of $\sigma(X)$ are many events of the form $\{X\ \text{has property (P)}\}$, for instance if $X$ is the outcome of a dice throw, $\sigma(X)$ contains, e.g. $\{X = 3\}, \{X = 1\}$.

Comment: Ah I'll need to read up a bit more on it. 

Also, the law of total expectation is defined as $E[X] = E[E[X|Y]]$. It's not clear to me how you adapted that to $E[X|A] = E[E[X|\mathcal{F}] | A]$. Could you explain this part or maybe show the middle steps? I was thinking it should it be $E[X | A] = E[E[X|\mathcal{F}, A]]$.

Comment: @user5965026: We should be careful with the notation. $E[X\mid Y]$ is a shorthand for $E[X\mid\sigma(Y)]$. If $A$ is an event, then when I write $E[X; A]$, this is not the same as $E[X\mid A]$. If you are familiar with integrals, $E[X; A]$ is a number equal to $\int_A X$, or in words the integral of $X$ over $A$, which you can think of as a weighted average of $X$, that assigns weight $1$ on $A$ and weight $0$ off of $A$, whereas $E[X\mid A]$ a random variable equal to $E[X\mid\sigma(A)]$. The section "Preliminaries" in the doc you linked has a nice, if somewhat terse intro to these ideas.

Comment: @user5965026: Also please see my updated answer. Hope that sheds some light on things.

Comment: So on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation, when they write $E[X] = E[E[X|Y]]$, this is really $E[X] = E[E[X|\sigma(Y)]]$? 

Also, I actually thought the semi colon and | notations were similar/interchangeable, and that $E[X ; A]$ is read as "expected value of the random variable X given that event A happens?" Which is equivalent to how I would have read $E[X|A]$. Which is defined as $\int x f_{X|D=A}(x|A) dx,$ where $D$ is a random variable.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107857/discussion-between-alex-ortiz-and-user5965026).